# Alternatives for @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "items" , allowGetters = true)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I need to avoid deserialization of an object without using @JsonIgnore or @JsonIgnoreProperties

I tried the following, but it always returns empty.

```java
 @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public Set<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another alternative available ?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to not use those annotations?

Comment: [READ_ONLY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html#READ_ONLY) means "Access setting that means that the property may only be read for serialization (value accessed via "getter" Method, or read from Field) but not written (set) during deserialization. Put another way, this would reflect "read-only POJO", in which value contained may be read but not written/set.". Do you initialize it in `POJO` in declaration: `Set<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: @chrylis -on strike- For swagger purposes, I need to avoid `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations to prevent deserialization.

Comment: @MichałZiober I do initialize it in tests. Thats where it is failing.